# Can't find any clear explaination about $paged variable in Wordpress documentations

Tags: wordpress, variables, wordpress-theming

I'm a newbie in Wordpress and today I have to read a code of a senior, the code is from the index.php file for a website:

```
<?php
          $i = 0;
          if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
          {
            if ($i == 0 && $paged < 1)
            {
              show_content("","12","card", "4");
            }
            elseif ($paged >= 1) { get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'card' ); }
            $i = $i + 1;
          }
          endwhile; else:
            echo("<p>No post found :(</p>");
          endif;
```

This block of loop is for displaying the posts in the homepage. When I search for the variable $paged I can only find the result about the global variable "page" and "pages" in Wordpress documentation, but not "paged". Then I asked my senior and even Chat GPT, both of them can tell me very clearly about the properties of the variable "paged" but when I asked them to send me a link to the documentation they couldn't find it either except for some Stackoverflow post about it. So I'm not sure is this variable some kind of out-of-date or why can't I find it on Wordpress official pages? Is there something bad about it that Wordpress team don't want to put it on their site along with other global variables? It'd be wonderful if somebody can explain it to me. Thanks in advance.

I tried to Goolgle a lot of place but can't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is really difficult to answer you with just a partial code.

The first thing that come in my mind about "paged" parameter is one of the parameters that you can use when requesting Db (via Wp_Query of other shortcode methods derivated form it like get_posts() which inherit some of its parameters).

In this context, it tells wordpress how many posts you want to retrive (and display) per page when displaying a paginated listing of post.

See here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters

```
paged (int) – number of page. Show the posts that would normally show up just on page X when using the “Older Entries” link.
```

That beeing said, in PHP, a variable can be global or not, and in the snippet you shared, there is nothing that tells us that $paged is a global variable, so it could simply be initiated earlier in the code (on in another php file included earlier on the page).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me alot. To be honest, the code is just like that, with some code to get header at the start and some to get footer at the end. What really confused me that the paged variable is used just like that, without declaration or call in the first place. I checked the list of Wordpress global variables but couldnt find that paged var. But except me, everyone else at my work seems to know and accept that variable as a global variable without the need of declaring at first.

Answer (score 0):

References to `$paged` likely refer to the `paged` query variable. WordPress supports pagination on several of its rewrite rules, ex: `/my-page-name/page/2`. To access the number (in the example, `2`), you would do this:

```php
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );
```

If the URL does not include pagination information (ex: `/my-page-name/`), then the `$paged` variable would default to the value of the second parameter, in this case `1`.

More:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've read the link above but it didn't say much about the thing that the paged variable can be used as a global variable without declaring it in the first place. In fact my senior used it without declaring like in the code I posted. That make me wonder why Wordpress doesn't say anything clearly like "you can use the paged variable as a global variable without the need to declare it". Sorry for my bad English :(